# How to enable Rndis and MTP together on Android

Tags: android, windows, android-10.0, mtp, rndis

I need to share wifi and storage from android to windiws, that is eable mtp and rndis at the same time.
Now I have modify th init.msm.usb.confifs.rc, add a new config "mtp,rndis,adb" in it.MTP can work correctlly, but there is a yellow excalmatory mark on device management on Windows.

I would like to ask how I can enable them together, MTP and RNDIS?
Thanks very much.